# Make post permanent in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is the php code that records the data and publishes it (post.php):

```
$titus=$_POST['titus'];
$des=$_POST['des'];
$link=$_POST['link'];
$sql=mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO titus(titus, des, link)VALUES ('$titus', '$des', '$link')");


$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * from titus
where idpod = (select max(idpod) from titus)");

while($postagem = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)){

    echo $postagem = $_POST['titus'] .'<br>';
    echo $postagem = $_POST['des'] .'<br>';
    echo $postagem = $_POST['link'] .'<br>';
```

This is the button that triggers post.php

```
<form action="postar.php" method="POST">
<button type="submit" class="pubi">Publish</button>
</form>
```

I need that as soon as I click on the button the publication will be permanent in its place, so that when there is the next publication, it becomes a list.

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: how to result in a permanent post, which is like a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the data that is stored in `$postagem` in your echo statements. Currently, you are assigning your POST values to `$postagem` instead of using the members within the `$postagem` object. [See the PHP manual on mysqli_fetch_object for more info on this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php).

Your code should look something like this:

```
while($postagem = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)){

    echo $postagem->titus .'<br>';
    echo $postagem->des .'<br>';
    echo $postagem->link .'<br>';
```

Also, your current code is going to try and insert data every time it is run, even if the required fields don't exist in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: Hello, I'll take a look, it's not a list yet, but I'll study this link you sent, to see what I can get, thank you very much =)